# I got the null values for tenantId and Userinfo in Authentication Result

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, bots, office365api, botframework

In one of my current Bot development, I was implemented AAD authentication using sign-in card.

This is the URL to login http://localhost:3979/api/{activity.From.Id}/login

After entered the user credentials in website it will be redirected to my html page.

This is the code I wrote in my **LoginController.cs**

```
    public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/{userid}/login")]

    public RedirectResult Login(string userid)
    {
        //return Redirect(String.Format("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&resource={2}",
        //    Constants.Constants.ADClientId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Constants.Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/authorize"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://graph.windows.net/")));

        return Redirect(String.Format("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}",
            Constants.Constants.ADClientId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Constants.Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/authorize")));
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/{userid}/authorize")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authorize(string userid, string code)
    {
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/");
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(Constants.Constants.ADClientId, Constants.Constants.ADClientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(Constants.Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/authorize"), cc, "https://api.office.com/discovery/");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ar.AccessToken))
        {               
            var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));
            if (stateClient != null)
            {
                var getData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid);
                //var getData = await client.B.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid);
                getData.Data = ar.Serialize();
                var foo = await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid, getData);
                //var foo = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid, getData);
            }
            //return Request.CreateResponse(foo);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("/loggedin.html", UriKind.Relative);
            return response;
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    }
}
```

For the first time I got the entire values in authentication result of this resource https://api.office.com/discovery/.

after login successfully, I am trying to get the calendar events using Office 365 API's for that I get the accestoken related with individual resource Uri's at that time I got the accestoken but tenant ID ,user info is null and also multipletimesrefreshtoken is false.

This is the code I wrote for getting calendar events using Office365 API's.

```
var events = await O365Autodiscovery.GetO365CalenderEvents(httpClient, ac, sfboResourceAppId, clientId, redirectUri, userCredential, ar);

 public class O365Autodiscovery
{
    internal static string O365AutoDiscoveryUri = "https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/services";

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RootObject> GetO365CalenderEvents(HttpClient httpClient, AuthenticationContext authenticationContext, String sfboResourceAppId,
            string clientId, string redirectUri, UserCredential uc,AuthenticationResult ar)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Now we'll call O365 Autodiscovery to get the root/oauth/user URI");
        var o365ApplicationHost = Helpers.ReduceUriToProtoAndHost(O365Autodiscovery.O365AutoDiscoveryUri);

        var O365AutoDiscoveryUserRootUri = DoO365AutoDiscovery(httpClient, authenticationContext, o365ApplicationHost, clientId, redirectUri, uc, ar);

        Debug.WriteLine("Now we'll get the O365 Applications URI for the user");
        var events =await GetO365UserResourceUri(httpClient, authenticationContext, await O365AutoDiscoveryUserRootUri, clientId, redirectUri, uc);

        return events;
    }

    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DoO365AutoDiscovery(HttpClient httpClient, AuthenticationContext authenticationContext, String sfboResourceAppId, string clientId, string redirectUri, UserCredential uc, AuthenticationResult ar)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

        //authenticationResult = await AzureAdAuth.GetAzureAdToken(authenticationContext, sfboResourceAppId, clientId, redirectUri, uc);

        string o365CalenderServiceRootUri = string.Empty;

        //Debug.WriteLine("Using this access token " + result.AccessToken);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.AccessToken);
        var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(O365AutoDiscoveryUri).Result;
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Called " + O365AutoDiscoveryUri);
            var resultString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("DoO365Discovery URI " + resultString);
            dynamic resultObject = JObject.Parse(resultString);
            foreach(var service in resultObject.value)
            {
                if (service.capability == "Calendar")
                {
                    o365CalenderServiceRootUri = service.serviceEndpointUri;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("DoO365Discovery Root URI is " + o365CalenderServiceRootUri);
        }
        return o365CalenderServiceRootUri+ "/me/events";
    }

    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RootObject> GetO365UserResourceUri(HttpClient httpClient, AuthenticationContext authenticationContext, String O365UserDiscoveryUri, string clientId,
        string redirectUri, UserCredential uc)
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
           authenticationResult = await AzureAdAuth.GetAzureAdToken(authenticationContext, O365UserDiscoveryUri, clientId, redirectUri, uc);
            //var refreshToken = MessagesController.password;
           // authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(MessagesController.password, new ClientCredential(Constants.ADClientId, Constants.ADClientSecret), O365UserDiscoveryUri);

            string O365UserResourceUri = String.Empty;

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
            var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(O365UserDiscoveryUri).Result;

            Debug.WriteLine("Called " + O365UserDiscoveryUri);
            var resultString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("GetO365UserResourceUri Body " + resultString);
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultString);
            return jsonObject;               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve it.

-Pradeep

Comment: You might consider using [AuthBot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AuthBot) for your AAD authentication needs.

Comment: Did you find a solution at the end?

Comment: @user2297037 No...